# Magento 2.0 and Laravel 5.2 under same subdomain

Tags: php, magento, laravel, nginx

I'm trying to run a Laravel app: http://www.example.com, and a Magento app: http://www.example.com/shop. The problem is, they both have their own full application directory structure including separate public (document root) directories and I'm having trouble creating the appropriate directory structure and nginx configuration for it.

I know I can set up a completely different subdomain/vhost for Magento under http://shop.example.com, but my client would like them both under the same subdomain. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Would a location alias not work?  (I haven't tried it so I can't vouch for it ATM)

Something like

`location /shop {
    root /var/www/magento;
}`